# Use declare to exclude or include parts of queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was just wondering if it was possible to exclude or include parts of a query.
By declaring a variable as yes or no. This would make things much easier then declaring every value in for example the 'IN' clause.

Example stated below

**Startingpoint**

```
SELECT 
    E.Id, E.Name
FROM 
    Employees AS E
WHERE 
    E.Email LIKE '%@company.com'
    AND E.Id NOT IN ('1001,1002,1009,1115,2000')
    AND E.Team = 0
```

**Ideal situation**

```
DECLARE @Includemanagers nvarchar (255) = 'No'

SELECT 
    E.Id, E.Name
FROM 
    Employees AS E
WHERE 
    E.Email LIKE '%@company.com'
    AND CASE 
           WHEN @Includemanagers = 'No' 
              THEN E.Id NOT IN ('1001,1002,1009,1115,2000') 
        END
    AND E.Team = 0
```

I know the syntax is not correct. And I doubt if this is possible.

> For reference in the future two correct answers are given.
>
> Use answer from @Jamiec when you DO NOT want to include PRINT statement
>
> Use answer from @Prdp when you want to include print statement

Comment: You may also use the `CASE` to set the values of the NOT IN. For instance, `NOT IT '1001,1002,1009,1115,2000'` or `NOT IN '999999999'` depending on the value of `@Includemanagers`.

Comment: Can you clarify why you have `PRINT 'Managers are included in this query'` - do you really want that printed, or was that to just demonstrate to us what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jamiec thats was just for demonstrating purposes I will exclude this from the post to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple `OR` condition

```
DECLARE @Includemanagers nvarchar (255) = 'No'

SELECT E.Id, E.Name
FROM Employees AS E
WHERE E.Email LIKE '%@company.com'
AND (@IncludeManagers = 'yes' 
     OR (@IncludeManagers = 'no' AND E.Id NOT IN (1001,1002,1009,1115,2000 ))
AND E.Team = 0
```

(Note that your `IN` clause was quoted, and that wont work. Corrected in this answer)

Comment: Your `IN` clause will not parse this as comma separated string :-)

Comment: @Shnugo thanks, I just copied OP code, didnt spot that. Corrected.

Comment: This was indeed what I was looking for and like you stated below this doesn't make complex queries unnecessary complex. This is great to declare some simple filters.

Answer (score 1):

Use Conditional Statement : `IF`

```
IF @Includemanagers <> 'No' 
  BEGIN 
       PRINT 'Managers are included in this query' 
       SELECT E.id, 
              E.NAME 
       FROM   employees AS E 
       WHERE  E.email LIKE '%@company.com' 
         AND E.team = 0 
  END 
ELSE 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT E.id, 
             E.NAME 
      FROM   employees AS E 
      WHERE  E.email LIKE '%@company.com' 
             AND E.id NOT IN ( 1001, 1002, 1009, 1115, 2000 ) 
             AND E.team = 0 
  END
```

Comment: I dont think this is going to do what the OP expected. I'm pretty sure they sill want results when that is set to `No`, just not including managers.

Comment: @Jamiec - I understood this way. Lets wait for OP's reply. May be am wrong

Comment: @Jamiec - Hope it makes some sense now

Comment: It does, and now our answers give roughly the same results. There is a reason I prefer not to use `IF...ELSE` logic for this in sql and it goes something like this - when those queries get more complex (as the invariably do) you end up with 2 almost extact duplicates of the same query. Some developer comes and adds a column to one, but forgets the other.... cue your app crashing weirdly when an expected result is missing. By using simple boolean logic in the `WHERE` this does not happen.

Comment: @Prdp and to add on Jamiec: This approach is not useable in *ad-hoc* sql. No `VIEW` no `inline-TVF`, which is a huge backdraw in my eyes...

Comment: @Jamiec - Whenever I see such question I never use `IF` logic I know there are many drawbacks I will always go with `AND/OR` logic. That `PRINT` statement in OP's query made me to use `IF` condition

Comment: @Shnugo - Completely agree with you. All just because of that `PRINT` statement in OP's query :D

Comment: @Prdp yep, I agree and have asked OP to clarify that point. If they really want that `PRINT` (for some reason) then I agree your answer is the only way to go.

Comment: @Prdp Oh yes, I see. I was not one of the down voters, but now I'm one of the up-voters :-)

Comment: @Shnugo - Thank you.  Btw you cannot survive here if care about downvotes so no worries ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are after, but you can do something like this with CASE functions:

```
DECLARE @Includemanagers nvarchar (255) = 'No'

SELECT 
    E.Id, E.Name
FROM 
    Employees AS E
WHERE 
    E.Email LIKE '%@company.com'
    AND 1 = CASE 
           WHEN @Includemanagers = 'No' 
              CASE WHEN  E.Id NOT IN (1001,1002,1009,1115,2000) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            ELSE 1 
        END
    AND E.Team = 0
```